# Out-File tab-delimited file issue

Tags: csv, powershell, delimiter

Every day I get many CSV Files that I need to import into a system. But before I can import them I need to encode ALL of them to UTF-8 and then upload them one by one. That's why I wanted a script, that encodes all *.csv Files to UTF-8 and then merges them to one file.

The script is working fine, but when I export the file, the first tab is been removed, which is a big problem.

How one File looks before it is encoded and merged:

```
USERID  ACTIVE  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    EMAIL   LANGUAGE    HOSTPRIVILEGE   TIMEZONE    DIVISION    DEPARTMENT  PROJECT OTHER   CUSTOM5 CUSTOM6 CUSTOM7 CUSTOM8 CUSTOM9 CUSTOM10    COUNTRY
    Y   <firstname> <lastname>  <name@mail.com> de  <text>  <text>                          <randomnumber>
```

(It looks like, Stackoverflow doesn't like TABs? Or im just to noobish.. :S)

Actually the second row begins with one tab, then every "block" is seperated by one tab. Except the last one, ther are 7 tabs between "text" and "randomnumber".

When I run the script it looks like this:

```
USERID  ACTIVE  FIRSTNAME   LASTNAME    EMAIL   LANGUAGE    HOSTPRIVILEGE   TIMEZONE    DIVISION    DEPARTMENT  PROJECT OTHER   CUSTOM5 CUSTOM6 CUSTOM7 CUSTOM8 CUSTOM9 CUSTOM10    COUNTRY
Y   <firstname> <lastname>  name@mail.com   de  <text>  <text>                          <randomnumber>              
Y   <firstname> <lastname>  name@mail.com   de  <text>  <text>                          <randomnumber>
```

The first tab gets lost.

And here is the PowerShell script:

```
Copy-Item ".\1_Input\*.csv" ".\2_cache"
Get-ChildItem ".\2_Cache\*.csv" | foreach {
  (Get-Content $_.FullName) | Set-Content $_.FullName -Encoding UTF8
}
ls ".\2_cache" -Fi *.csv | ipcsv |
  ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation |
  % { $_ -replace '"', ''} |
  Out-File ".\3_output\concat.csv" -fo -en utf8
Remove-Item ".\2_cache\*.csv"
```

EDIT: I found a "workaround", i added the parameter

```
ipcsv -delimiter "`t"
```

but i get errors when i add the parameter to **ConvertTo-CSV**. So now it is exported with the delimiter ",". But the System thankfully is able to read import it also comma separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is convert the files to UTF-8 and then concatenate them it would be a lot simpler to get the header line from one file, then skip the header on all files as you write them to the output file:

```
$files   = @(Get-ChildItem '.\1_Input\*.csv')
$outfile = 'concat.csv'

Get-Content $files[0] -TotalCount 1 | Set-Content $outfile -Encoding UTF8
$files | ForEach-Object {
  Get-Content $_.FullName | Select-Object -Skip 1
} | Add-Content $outfile -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfect! I "converted" the final Scripts to .exe, so even "dummies" should be able to use it. But then Kaspersky Antivirus identifies it as a trojan, lol. Damn it. Maybe i will stay with the .ps1 Script..
EDIT: I used PS2EXE to "convert" the script, if someone wants to know..

Comment: Try to use PowerGUI instead (free), maybe you'll get around Kaspersky better. There must also be a whitelist system in some way.